# How do you type the dollar sign when you have mathjax installed?

Tags: mathjax

So in Jekyll and Markdown, I can't type $ or its HTML equivalent code, and not \$ nor $\$$. How should I type the dollar sign?

Answer (score 16):

To prevent MathJax from using the dollar sign as a delimiter, you can put it in a span, like so:

```
<span>$</span>
```

Alternatively, you can enable `processEscapes` and then you can use the backslash escape `\$` for the dollar sign.

Comment: what is processEscapes? please!

Comment: The span trick isn't working for me--the end tag is interpreted as text in math mode. :-(

Answer (score 7):

Enable `processEscapes`:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
    processEscapes: true
  }
});
```

Then you can simply use `\$` to get a plain `$`.

Comment: If using Jekyll, you will need to escape the \\, too, so \\$ will produce a plain `$`.

Answer (score 1):

I used mathjax's dollar symbol in that paragraph. It works.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I disable dollar signs completely: my settings (in a script tag) are:

```js
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['\\\\(', '\\\\)']],
    displayMath: [['\\\\[', '\\\\]']]
  },
  svg: {
    fontCache: 'global'
  }
};
```

so that I *have* to use \(...\) or \[...\] rather than $x$ and $$y$$.

Comment: View the source of https://w.allsup.co/sandbox/MathJax as an example -- note that dollar signs appear as is, but \\(...\\) and \\[...\\] are handled by MathJax. (That site is my personal wiki that I use as a note-taking system ala Obsidian.)