# How to use "$" in non Math context while using MathJax in a Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

How can I bypass MathJax recognizing dollar signs as inline delimiter in non-math setting?

I am using MathJax for displaying Math Equations in my blog, but not all my posts are Math Related so everytime I use '$' symbol MathJax gets triggered and makes my post be interpreted as Math text.

I have tried using the following tricks to render '$' sign without directly typing it.

```
Dollar HexCode = &#x24;
Dollar HTMLcode = &#36;
DollarHTMLentity = &dollar;
but MathJax still catches me.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.MathJax = {
    TeX: {
      extensions: ['AMSsymbols.js', '[a11y]/accessibility-menu.js']
    },
    menuSettings: {
      collapsible: false,
      autocollapse: false
    },
    messageStyle: 'none',
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [
        ['$', '$'],
        ["\\(", "\\)"]
      ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  };
</script>
<!--MATHJAX SCRIPT ENDS-->
<script async='async' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'></script>

<div class="post-body">
  This is the regular post<br> $100 The Whole Part Between These Two Dollar Signs Gets Caught By MathJax$100 This Part Doesn't Get Caught And Is Safely Displayed On The Page$200 This Part Gets Caught, $00 And This Part Doesn't $300 This Part Should Have
  Been Caught But It Bypasses Because The Closing Dollar Sign Is Missing.
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="post-body">
  Here I use "&amp;#x24;"<br> &#x24;100 The Whole Part Between These Two Dollar Signs Gets Caught By MathJax&#x24;100 This Part Doesn't Get Caught And Is Safely Displayed On The Page&#x24;200 This Part Gets Caught, &#x24;200 And This Part Doesn't &#x24;300
  This Part Should Have Been Caught But It Bypasses Because The Closing Dollar Sign Is Missing.
</div>
<br>
<div class="post-body">
  Here I'll use "&amp;#36;" &#36;100 The Whole Part Between These Two Dollar Signs Gets Caught By MathJax &#36;100 This Part Doesn't Get Caught And Is Safely Displayed On The Page &#36;200 This Part Gets Caught, &#36;200 And This Part Doesn't &#36;300 This
  Part Should Have Been Caught But It Bypasses Because The Closing Dollar Sign Is Missing.
</div>
<br>
<div class="post-body">
  Here I use "&amp;dollar;" &dollar;100 The Whole Part Between These Two Dollar Signs Gets Caught By MathJax &dollar;100 This Part Doesn't Get Caught And Is Safely Displayed On The Page &dollar;200 This Part Gets Caught, &dollar;200 And This Part Doesn't
  &dollar;300 This Part Should Have Been Caught But It Bypasses Because The Closing Dollar Sign Is Missing.
</div>
```

Sorry for the lengthy Code but I think the Code Describes what I mean... I need to use "$" sign but I can't afford to skip MathJax from my entire blog.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030033/how-do-you-type-the-dollar-sign-when-you-have-mathjax-installed)? Looks like a duplicate but I'm not familiar with MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `processEscapes: true`, you can use `\$` to represent a `$` without it being used as a MathJax delimiter.

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/preprocessors/tex2jax.html#configure-tex2jax

Comment: I wonder how to achieve this in KaTeX?